# Creating a list of times with loops instead of manual entry

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list with options in 30 minute intervals from 9am-5pm.
e.g.

```
    times = ['09:00-09:30', '09:30-10:00', '10:00-10:30', '10:30-11:00', '11:00-11:30', '11:30-12:00',
            '12:00-12:30', '12:30-13:00', '13:00-13:30', '13:30-14:00', '14:00-14:30', '14:30-15:00',
            '15:00-15:30', '15:30-16:00', '16:00-16:30', '16:30-17:00']
```

How would I be able to accomplish this but using loops or a method that doesn't look this verbose?

Comment: How would the desired output look like? You say you want to create a dictionary but define a list.

Comment: Sorry, that's an error on my part, I meant a list.

Comment: If you have the option of using a 3rd party python package, you can look into dateutil.rrule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an iterable of `datetime` objects, starting at 9 o'clock.

```
import datetime

fmt = '%H:%M'
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00', fmt)
times = (start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30*i) for i in range(17))
```

Turn the `datetime` objects back to strings.

```
times_str = (t.strftime(fmt) for t in times)
```

Iterate over `times_str` in pairs. The [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe for this called **`pairwise`**. You can either copy-paste the function or import it from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) (which needs to be installed).

```
from more_itertools import pairwise
result = ['-'.join(times) for times in pairwise(times_str)]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(result)
['09:00-09:30', '09:30-10:00', '10:00-10:30', '10:30-11:00', '11:00-11:30', '11:30-12:00', '12:00-12:30', '12:30-13:00', '13:00-13:30', '13:30-14:00', '14:00-14:30', '14:30-15:00', '15:00-15:30', '15:30-16:00', '16:00-16:30', '16:30-17:00']
```

You could encapsulate everything with a function.

```
import datetime
from more_itertools import pairwise

def timepairs(start:datetime.datetime, steps:int, delta:datetime.timedelta, fmt='%H:%M'):
    times = (start + delta*i for i in range(steps + 1))
    times_str = (t.strftime(fmt) for t in times)
    return ['-'.join(times) for times in pairwise(times_str)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00', '%H:%M')
>>> timepairs(start, 16, datetime.timedelta(minutes=30))
['09:00-09:30', '09:30-10:00', '10:00-10:30', '10:30-11:00', '11:00-11:30', '11:30-12:00', '12:00-12:30', '12:30-13:00', '13:00-13:30', '13:30-14:00', '14:00-14:30', '14:30-15:00', '15:00-15:30', '15:30-16:00', '16:00-16:30', '16:30-17:00']
>>> 
>>> start = datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00', '%H:%M')
>>> timepairs(start, 12, datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
['00:00-00:05', '00:05-00:10', '00:10-00:15', '00:15-00:20', '00:20-00:25', '00:25-00:30', '00:30-00:35', '00:35-00:40', '00:40-00:45', '00:45-00:50', '00:50-00:55', '00:55-01:00']
```

Comment: This is even more than what I was asking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

fmt='%H:%M'
time=datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00',fmt)
min30=datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
times=[]

for i in range(16):
    times.append('%s-%s' % ( time.strftime(fmt), (time+min30).strftime(fmt)))
    time+=min30
print times
```

Comment: This is what I used as an answer before i read timgeb 's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..:

```
hours = 9
minutes = 0

n = 10
cal = {}

for i in range(n):
    key = str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes)
    cal[key] = 10

    if i%2 != 0:
        hours += 1

    minutes += 30
    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0

print(cal)
```

You can change the number of times you run the loop. Change the condition to run until `hours` reach your desired time.

You can also make some edits to get the key as `09:00` instead of `9:0`.

Basically, for a dict, you just have to have a key value as a string. You can use any string you want, and assign a value to it. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple code with `pandas`:

```
In [2]:pandas.date_range("09:00", "17:00", freq="30min").time
Out[2]:
array([datetime.time(9, 0), datetime.time(9, 30), datetime.time(10, 0),
       datetime.time(10, 30), datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(11, 30),
       datetime.time(12, 0), datetime.time(12, 30), datetime.time(13, 0),
       datetime.time(13, 30), datetime.time(14, 0), datetime.time(14, 30),
       datetime.time(15, 0), datetime.time(15, 30), datetime.time(16, 0),
       datetime.time(16, 30), datetime.time(17, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: How do you get strings as in the OP's example?